# Get attachments of list items with SPServices

Tags: spservices, attachments

How can I fetch the attachments (the URL, to be precise) of a list item with SPServices (the jQuery library)?

Answer (score 9):

### How to retrieve attachment files using SPServices

```
function getAttachmentFiles(listName,listItemId,complete) 
{
   $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetAttachmentCollection",
        async: false,
        listName: listName,
        ID: listItemId,
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            var attachmentFileUrls = [];    
            $(xData.responseXML).find("Attachment").each(function() {
               var url = $(this).text();
               attachmentFileUrls.push(url);
            });
            complete(attachmentFileUrls);
        }
   });
}
```

**Usage**

```
getAttachmentFiles('Requests',1,printAttachments);

function printAttachments(urls){
    for(var i =0; i< urls.length; i++){
        console.log(urls[i]);     
    };    
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up to sleepy people like me, don't forget to change the `listName` and `ID` to your list and the item ID which has the image on the func. Else you'll get a `_vti_bin/Lists.asmx 500 (Internal Server Error)` error in the console)

Answer (score 1):

This should get you where you need to go:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebProperties, "SP.js");            
var attachmentFiles;

function getWebProperties() {
    var itemId=2;
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var attachmentFolder=web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/City/Attachments/'+itemId);
    attachmentFiles= attachmentFolder.get_files();
    ctx.load(attachmentFiles);              
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onSuccess),Function.createDelegate(this,this.onFailed));
}

function onSuccess(sender, args) {                                      
    var i=0;
    for(var file in attachmentFiles) {                              
        alert(attachmentFiles.itemAt(i).get_serverRelativeUrl());
        i++;
    }
}

function onFailed(sender, args) {
    alert("sorry!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to amend an alternate formation of the onSuccess function that worked better for me:

```
function onSuccess(sender, args) {                                      
    var i = 0;
    while (attachmentFiles.itemAt(i)) {
        var file = attachmentFiles.itemAt(i).get_serverRelativeUrl();
        alert(file);
        i++;
    }
}
```